# Converting string to datetime with characters in string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a string format like so: `2021-10-30 08:59:20 (PST)`

My code is: `pd.to_datetime(dftest, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S (%Z)')`

And the error is:

```
time data '2021-10-30 11:57:07 (PDT)' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S (%Z)' (match)
```

I am guessing that it has to do with the (PST), as from another data source this conversion works fine without when it does not have that in it. I'm assuming there is something very simple I am missing here

Comment: It looks like this timezone is not recognized, this works fine with `GMT` or `EST` in place of `PST`

Answer (score 1):

**#1. Simple way**

Why don't you remove the ' (PST)'?

If you only consider PST time in your dataset, you can simply do this:

```
df['time'] = '2021-10-30 08:59:20 (PST)'
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x[:-6])  # removing ' (PST)'
df['test'] = pd.to_datetime(df['test'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', utc=True) + timedelta(hours=8)
```

I removed the ' (PST)' and converted it to datetime with timezone UTC, then I added 8 hours to make it PST timezone.

- Pacific Standard Time (PST) is UTC-8.
- Pacific Daylight Time (PDT) is UTC-7.

Or you can use a specific timezone such as tz='Europe/Berlin', see this:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html

**#2. Advanced Way**

by using `dateparser` module (https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can deal datetime data from any timezone, such as PST, EST, etc.:

```
import datetime
import dateparser  # pip install dateparser

data = ['2021-10-30 08:59:20 (PST)', '2021-10-30 08:59:20 (EST)']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(dateparser.parse)
print(df)
df['UTC_time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc))
print(df)
```

```
                        time                  UTC_time
0  2021-10-30 08:59:20-08:00 2021-10-30 16:59:20+00:00
1  2021-10-30 08:59:20-05:00 2021-10-30 13:59:20+00:00
```

Comment: I guess OP needs to have the timezone, it's quite an important information. Imagine I gave you as meeting point a street number without the street name. Pretty useless, no ? ;)

Comment: @mozway You're right. I have added the timezone information on the code. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Yes, the intermediate step I found was just to remove the timezone. However, I would like to keep it in a future version. Unfortunately, I cant just set it to PST, as the timezones are different with several rows.

Ideally would like to know why the original code did not work, and what/if there is a solution similar to the original code (just passing the datetime method, with the "correct" format)

Comment: @yeff In cosideration of the scenario you mentioned, I tried to solve this problem using dateparser module so that people can flexibilty convert this type of datetime processing (see #2. Advanced way) :)